# I've impregnated a cow. How long until it gives birth?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

My cow is pregnant, but the game doesn't include any instructions for pregnancy, so I'm not sure how long it takes for the cow to give birth. Furthermore, how long after birth does it take the baby cow to produce milk?

Comment: [You're welcome](http://www.cattletoday.com/gestation.shtml).

Comment: NOBODY WANTS TO KNOW ABOUT YOUR TURTLECOW BABIES.

Comment: We need more titles like this.

Comment: A title that makes you think that theres zoophilia involved always gets a +1 in my book.

Comment: Instructions for pregnancy? Well, when a girl cow and a boy cow love each other very very much...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you impregnate a cow, there is a 50/50 chance that it will be either a bull or a cow.

I believe it's the same when you breed 2 different kinds of cattle (E.g., Star Bull + Normal Cow = Star Bull/Cow or Normal Bull/Cow)

It takes 21 days for a cow to give birth. I recommend impregnating your cow(s) to give birth at least 3 times to unlock Jersey Cows (buy from Neil). (10 hatched eggs for Silkie chickens)

It takes 20 days (of feeding) before the calf become adult. Chicks takes are 8 days to become an adult.

If you choose to buy the "Miracle Potion" to impregnate your cow, the calf that was born will be an exact copy of it's mother. It was always a female and always be the same kind of cow it's mother was.

I believe the baby calf will have half the hearts of the mother.

Your animals cannot conceive if they are dirty or sick.

For chickens, if more than two are scheduled the hatch only the first two will hatch on the schedule day, any other will have to wait till the next day. Chickens that lay Golden Eggs don't pass this onto their children.

Comment: Potion of Cow Cloning. Neat.

Comment: Psh, it's not *that* much of a miracle. [Lizards do it all the time!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis)